# BatchNormalization backpropagation

Tags: artificial-intelligence

[image: Diagram of batch normalization]

While doing cs231n assignment, I got stuck with batchnorm_backward_alt(BatchNormalization backpropogation with an efficient way). I've tried many ways, but failed. please help me with this. it would be grateful if there's an explanation plz.

my code

```
def batchnorm_backward_alt(dout, cache):

dx, dgamma, dbeta = None, None, None
N=dout.shape[0]
xmu,var,xhat,gamma,eps,mu=cache
sigma=np.sqrt(var+eps)

dbeta=np.sum(dout,axis=0)
dgamma=np.sum(dout*xhat,axis=0)

dy=dout*gamma
dsig=-xmu/(sigma**2)
dvar=np.sum(dy*dsig/(2*sigma),axis=0)

dmu=np.sum(-dy/sigma+dvar*xmu*2/N,axis=0)
dx=dvar*2*xmu/N+dmu/N
pass
```

I wrote my code based on the chain rule that I've calculated

answer code that I've found

```
dx, dgamma, dbeta = None, None, None


N, D = dout.shape

xhat, gamma, xmu, ivar, sqrtvar, var, eps = cache

dxhat = dout * gamma

dx = 1.0/N * ivar * (N*dxhat - np.sum(dxhat, axis=0) - xhat*np.sum(dxhat*xhat, axis=0))
dbeta = np.sum(dout, axis=0)
dgamma = np.sum(xhat*dout, axis=0)
```

Comment: Are you writing a program? Using a library? Is this just a conception question? Most people here don't know what cs231n is.

Comment: cs231n is a famous lecture in the field of computer vision and I'm not using any libraries. this is just writing the code for batchnormalization by myself

Comment: Help people help you: Link the assignment, show your attempt and how it behaves, explain what you'd expect instead.

Comment: please show what you tried and what you are trying to achieve